# What should a C# object initializer for a Dictionary<string, string[]> look like?

Tags: c#, dictionary, object-initializers

I am trying to declare a dictionary whose values are string arrays. How can I do this?

I tried the following code (which does not work):

```
Dictionary<string, string[]> NewDic = new Dictionary<string,string[]>
{
    {"Key_0", {"Value_0.0", "Value_0.1"}},
    {"Key_1", {"Value_1.0", "Value_1.1", "Value_1.2"}},
}
```

Comment: the second parameter should be in square brakets isn't

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to specify that your values are arrays like:

using [implicitly typed array](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384090.aspx)

```
 {"Key_0", new[] {"Value_0.0", "Value_0.1"}},
```

Or explicitly specifying the type

```
 {"Key_0", new string[] {"Value_0.0", "Value_0.1"}},
```

So your class could look like:

```
public static class NewClass
{
    private static Dictionary<string, string[]> NewDic = new Dictionary<string, string[]>
    {
        {"Key_0", new[] {"Value_0.0", "Value_0.1"}},
        {"Key_1", new string[] {"Value_1.0", "Value_1.1", "Value_1.2"}},
    };
}
```

Comment: @Gaduks, you are welcome, *Although*, not directly related but you can also use [indexed members](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dn683793.aspx) with C# 6.0 like `["Key_0"] = new[] { "Value_0.0", "Value_0.1" },`